# Signing and submiting an xcode project to appstore without a mac

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store, virtual-machine, smartface.io

Is there any cloud mac services for signing and providing me with an ipa of my xcode project and enabling me to upload apps to appstore without a physical mac?

I developed my project solely on windows using an ios emulator for windows (smartface) and published my project as xcode project. So far I didn't need mac. Now I'm looking for ways to submit my app to appstore without buying a mac. Is it technically possible? I can't afford buying a mac now...

Answer (score 1):

Smartface App Studio offers iOS development environment (Development, Test, Debug etc..) without a MAC.

However, App Submission to AppStore requires a MAC due to Apple license restrictions. Smartface App Stuido is a development environment, you need another solution for distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like a [virtualmacosx](http://virtualmacosx.com/) cloud services. Smartface.io does not have cloud osx services.

Answer (score -1):

You can actually sign Apps using openssl without the proprietary key manager on Mac.

Checkout https://www.kryogenix.org/days/2014/02/11/building-a-phonegap-ios-app-from-ubuntu-entirely-without-mac-os-x/ for a tutorial on how to do it.  You're still going to need macOS to upload to iTunes though.